# Microsoft Access to SQL Server Transition - Invalid use of null on insert

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, null, ms-access-2010

I'm migrating a legacy Microsoft Access application to use SQL Server as the backend. I've noticed since switching to SQL Server all the inserts are now coming up with invalid use of null errors.

From some testing I've found this is due to how the VBA is written. The primary key is referenced before the record is created and not surprisingly it nulls.

```
Dim recordSet  As DAO.Recordset
Dim newID As Long

Set recordSet = dbLocal.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM tblUser", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
 With recordSet
  .AddNew
   newID = !UserID
  .Update
 End With
recordset.Close
```

Now this works fine in the old Access to Access application. How is it able to do so and how can i make this work with the new SQL Server back end?
(I am aware that I can change the code to not reference it however this occurs multiple times within the application and as such I would prefer not to).

Comment: Check the Access DB for default values on columns and if this code is correct replicated to SQL Server with `CONTRAINTS`

Comment: Is `UserID` an IDENTITY (AutoNumber in Access) column?

Comment: Yes, the value is no doubt coming from something like a SQL Server identity column. That won't get assigned a value until the .Update is executed.

Does the problem occur if you put the .Update line before the line that retrieves the value?

Comment: @Andre Yes it is the AutoNumber column in Access

Comment: @GregLow Yeah it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised this ever worked. The correct way to do it is like this:

```vb
With myRecordSet
    .AddNew
    ' Set all data columns (not the IDENTITY column)
    !Data = someData
    ' Save new record
    .Update

    ' Move the recordset pointer to the new record to read its ID
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
    newID = !UserID
    ' Done
    .Close
End With
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-lastmodified-property-dao

Comment: So there would be no way to resolve this without changing all instances where it inserts to SQL?

Comment: No, you will have to do that. @varilight

Comment: Well, even in a very large migration, I only  found about 4-5 places. For any insert that does not need to pick up the PK "id", then the code really does not need to be changed. So, yes you do have to modify any code that does a .addNew, and then picks up the PK autonumber you have to do a save with bookmark as per above. Looking at a recent migration, out of about 40 places, only about 4 of them were picking up that PK id, and the rest did not need any  change in the code. The same issue crops up on forms - a me.Dirty = False will force the write and autoumber to appear if the PK is required.